# Relationship between two tables, SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, rdbms

I want to make a relationship between AuthorComments and Reply to his comments.

Here is my **models.py**:

```
class AuthorComments(Base):

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    author_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('author.id'))
    name = db.Column(db.String(50))
    email = db.Column(db.String(50), unique=True)
    comment = db.Column(db.Text)
    live = db.Column(db.Boolean)

    comments = db.relationship('Reply', backref='reply', lazy='joined')

    def __init__(self,author, name, email, comment, live=True):

        self.author_id = author.id
        self.name = name
        self.email = email
        self.comment = comment
        self.live = live

class Reply(Base):

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    reply_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('author.id'))
    name = db.Column(db.String(50))
    email = db.Column(db.String(50), unique=True)
    comment = db.Column(db.Text)
    live = db.Column(db.Boolean)

    def __init__(self,author, name, email, comment, live=True):

        self.reply_id = author.id
        self.name = name
        self.email = email
        self.comment = comment
        self.live = live
```

Why am I getting this error:
**sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError**

`InvalidRequestError: One or more mappers failed to initialize - can't proceed with initialization of other mappers.  Original exception was: Could not determine join condition between parent/child tables on relationship AuthorComments.comments - there are no foreign keys linking these tables.  Ensure that referencing columns are associated with a ForeignKey or ForeignKeyConstraint, or specify a 'primaryjoin' expression.`

Comment: There is a lot of code in your question that is probably not needed to produce this error. Can you try to create a smaller example that still has your error?

Comment: if i removed `comments = db.relationship('Reply', backref='reply', lazy='joined')`, no errors appears, but the comment will reply to all the other comments not the specified one !!

Comment: Please edit your question to provide the full traceback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your trouble is that SQLAlchemy doesn't know, for a given row of the child table (`Reply`), which row of the parent table (`AuthorComments`) to select! You need to define a *foreign-key* column in `Reply` that references a column of its parent `AuthorComments`.

[Here](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/basic_relationships.html#one-to-many) is the documentation on defining one-to-many relationships in SQLAlchemy.

Something like this:

```
class AuthorComments(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'author_comment'
    ...

class Reply(Base):
    ...
    author_comment_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('author_comment.id'))
    ...
    author_comment = db.relationship(
        'AuthorComments',
        backref='replies',
        lazy='joined'
        )
```

will result in each `reply` acquiring a relationship to an `author_comment` such that `some_reply.author_comment_id == some_author_comment.id`, or `None` if no such equality exists.

The `backref` allows each `author_comment` to, reciprocally, have a relationship to a collection of replies called `replies`, satisfying the above condition.

Comment: i tried the code above, actually no errors appears except inside the database, i got a NULL value for all the author_comment_id, why !

Comment: i've solved the problem, but also the same, am getting the reply for all the comments !!!

Comment: @Reznov Make sure that you are actually updating the database *behind* SQLAlchemy when you add the foreign-key column. Just changing `models.py` won't add a column to the database. If you don't care about losing your data, you can quickly re-build your database using Flask-SQLAlchemy's `drop_all` and `create_all` commands [documented here](http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/2.1/binds/#creating-and-dropping-tables). Otherwise, I suggest you look into a migration tool like [Alembic](//alembic.zzzcomputing.com); it integrates nicely with Flask via [Flask-Migration](//flask-migrate.readthedocs.io)

Comment: @Reznov it is unclear whether you still have a problem, and if so, whether it is the same problem as expressed in your original question; your most recent comment doesn't scan syntactically.